# Best BIC value for K-means clusters

Tags: clustering, k-means, bic

I am using code from [Using BIC to estimate the number of k in KMEANS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90769/using-bic-to-estimate-the-number-of-k-in-kmeans/251169#251169) (answer by Prabhath Nanisetty) to find BIC values for K-means using different number of components. However, using iris dataset, I get following results:

```
N_clusters        BIC  
1         -863.896405          
2         -674.133038          
3         -616.557809           
4         -603.357368           
5         -582.428798           
6         -596.073710           
7         -590.086212           
8         -579.876476           
9         -554.665433
```

This is shown in following plot:

[image]

The plot after standardization of data:

[image]

Is is normal to have negative values for BIC. Which is the best number of clusters by BIC here, especially considering that iris data set has 3 groups? Most negative value in above list is for 1 cluster only.

Comment: I can't say anything about the program you used. But I can check by "my" [program](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/55160/3277) (which is how SPSS does it in two-step cluster analysis). If you are interested, please tell me whether you want the iris variables be standardized before k-means. Note also that BIC does not - as far as I know - check if there is _one_ vs or more-than-one clusters.

Comment: I have corrected the link in my question above. It takes you to the code I have used. Also, I have added plot obtained after standardization of data.

Comment: I also use the code from the link you mentioned but I think there's a misunderstanding there. When you calculate the euclidean distance make sure you don't square the result because you want the square root of the sum of squares. I tested with the squared distance and get the same results as you, but if I use the square root I get the expected results

Comment: Seems a good point. It will be great if you put this as a full answer, preferably with a figure.

Answer (score 2):

I also use the code from the link you provided.

First thing, it is normal to have negative values of BIC. As you are using `BIC = likelihood - penalty` you want to find the highest value, which in your first image clearly we would pick `N_clusters = 8` and in the second image `N_clusters = 9`.

I get almost the same if I use the squared euclidean distance:

[image]

If I use the euclidean distance I get the expected results and this is the formula I've been using because I've made some tests and it seems correct.

The results using the appropriate euclidean distance gives me this plot:

[image]

And here we can obviously see that the appropriate number of clusters to pick is 3 (Setosa, Versicolor and Virginica).

One last note is that it doesn't make sense to set your minimum `n_clusters` to 1, it should start with 2. I only started with 1 to make the plot look like yours.

Comment: The BIC is based on the likelihood, and the Gaussian likelihood has sums of squared Euclidean distances, not their root. The root is not correct just because here it delivers the result you think it should give. I'm not sure whether there's anything wrong with the code that points at $k=9$, this may well be, but what you are proposing here, regardless of whether it seems to work well, is not the BIC as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my results. But I used another program with pseudocode explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/55160/3277).

[image]

**BIC** recommends 3-cluster solution. Clustering was done of *standardized* **iris data** variables by k-means ([initial centres](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/317498/3277) by RUNFP method).

The scatterplot of the (standardized) data of the 3-cluster partition in the first two principal components (explaining 96% of the data) is below.

[image]

Comment: These results are clearly very different from mine and they fit with the data very well. Where is the problem in the code that I have used?

Comment: Will you excuse me if I leave digging in the code on yourself? There must be some mistake in it. Note, too, that the correct version of your code needs not give exactly the same results as mine because there exist not one algorithm/formula to calculate BIC for cluster validation. Here is my short overview on clustering validation criteria: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/358937/3277