# k means in python with BIC

Tags: machine-learning, python, k-means, bic

I am new to ML. I am trying to implement k-means which uses a BIC function that takes cluster and data points as arguments and returns BIC value. I need a function to find best k value that is maximise the BIC. Can anyone provide a code snippet for BIC function in python. I searched everywhere I couldn't find exact what I needed

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/5h2rbw/does_python_have_a_package_for_aicbic/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60823638/python-function-for-bayesiasn-information-criterion-bic)

Comment: Or this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90769/using-bic-to-estimate-the-number-of-k-in-kmeans

Comment: yes thank you all.... I found those links later