# Can I see Log-likelihood values for two-step clustering in SPSS?

Tags: clustering, spss, likelihood

I need to compare Two-step clustering with latent class analysis. As LCA is not possible in SPSS I did it in R, however, 2-step clustering in R is quite challenging, so I did it in SPSS. To compare it I need different measures including the values of log-likelihood. The question is can I obtain it somehow from the two-cluster analysis in SPSS?

Comment: See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/55160/3277) answer which explains how BIC can be computed as a clustering criterion. It uses the same formula of the LL as the TwoStep cluster analysis in SPSS

Answer (score 0):

SPSS Statistics TWOSTEP CLUSTER will not directly output a log-likelihood, only AIC or BIC when doing automatic selection of the number of clusters, so you'd have to dig into the formulas in the algorithms in order to manually calculate it.